# How do I not print a DataFrame's unique ID?

Tags: python, dataframe

I've got a data frame that prints a unique ID in the same cell as my id.

```
data = pd.DataFrame(video_details, columns = ['id', 'name', 'description'])
```

Code to save the data:

```
with open('data.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['ID']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames = fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({"ID":data})
```

My output looks like this: 0       data

I know CSV files require a "," between items, but how do I insert that comma into a unique ID? I tried to pop it but it always returned.

Comment: Your CSV code is not fetching anything from the dataframe.   Do you want to save the whole dataframe?  `df.to_csv` can do that in one step.

Comment: How are you setting `id`?

Comment: Comma is for separating fields. Your CSV file only has one field, so you don't need a comma. If you want multiple rows, you should write in a loop.

Comment: But it sounds like you just want `data['id'].to_csv('data.csv')`